# Environment passed in from Python is different in release and debug modes

Tags: python, visual-c++, bloomberg

I'm currently building a Python plugin, using Visual Studios
2012, and generating 64 bit code.  In addition, we're using the
Bloomberg library `blpapi`.  In the Python module which loads
our plugin, we set an environment variable before loading; the
code looks something like:

```
import os
import imp
directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.environ['__PYTHON_SYS_PATH_FOR_PROG__'] = directory
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('PyPROG', [ directory ])
if fp is not None:
    try:
        _mod = imp.load_module('PyPROG', fp, pathname, description)
    finally:
        fp.close()
```

There is a file `PyPROG.pyd` in the path, and it normally works
fine.  If we `import blpapi` before, however, it works in Debug
mode, but not in Release: the function `initPyPROG` is basically:

```
PyMODINIT_FUNC
initPyPROG()
{
    try {
        char const* syspath = getenv( "__PYTHON_SYS_PATH_FOR_PROG__" );
        std::string path = syspath != NULL ? syspath : "";
        bool verbose = getenv( "__PYTHON_PROG_VERBOSE__" ) != NULL;
        if ( path.empty() ) {
            // ...
        }
        //  ...
    } catch ( std::exception const& error ) {
        PyErr_SetString( PyExc_ImportError, error.what() );
    } catch ( ... ) {
        if ( PyErr_Occurred() == NULL ) {
            PyErr_SetString( PyExc_ImportError, "Unknown error initializing PyPROG" );
        }
    }
}
```

In release mode, after loading `blpapi`, we go into the
`path.empty()` branch; in debug mode, no, and if we don't load
`blpapi`, no.

If I set a breakpoint at the entry of the program, and look at
the environment in the debugger, `__PYTHON_SYS_PATH_FOR_PROG__`
is not present in the error case; it is in the debug build.  And
if I add a `DllMain` function, which dumps the environment to
a file when the dll is attached, the missing variable
`__PYTHON_SYS_PATH_FOR_PROG__` is the only difference.  (We
don't currently set `__PYTHON_PROG_VERBOSE__`.)

Also, there are no static variables which have constructors in
the module.  (It's a very small module, which does nothing but
load the other DLLs which do the real work.  Except that it
doesn't get that far.)

Has anyone else seen similar problems?  And where should I start
looking?  Given that the error takes place before any of my code
executes: is there a bug in Visual Studios?  (But if so, why
does it only trigger after loading `blpapi`?  Could it be
related to the load address in some way?)